# ARCHIVELOG in Oracle 12c multitenant PDB

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, multi-tenant, archive-log

In a Oracle 12c multitenant DB instance with multiple PDBs, is it possible to enable `ARCHIVELOG` mode on a single PDB?

Comment: ,Yes. but You must do this from the root container.

Comment: For _root container_  do you refer to CDB? In this way all PDBs will be affected, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean archivelog mode for one PDB but not others?

Comment: Yes. On a single PDB not affecting others...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because all PDBs share the same redo log files, it's not possible to enable archive log mode only for a specific PDB. All PDBs share the archive log mode of the CDB.

> Remember, the PDBs themselves don't have any instance (processes and memory areas) or control file and redo logs

[Oracle Database 12c Feature: Multitenant Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/multitenant-part1-pdbs-2193987.html)

Comment: I came to your own conclusion after looking at this [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-overview-container-database-cdb-12cr1) but not having found explicit in oracle documentation I was left with the doubt.